# Tabbed webparts in two rows

Tags: web-part, page-layout

I have been using a "tab script" to display multiple lists web parts on a page in "tab format". The script is working fine when there are just a few list web parts, but as the number of web parts increases the resulting page layout is turning out ugly. Can anyone suggest a way to split the tabs view on two or more rows?

Below here is the code I am currently using to implement the tabs

```
<style type="text/css">
.et-tab {
BORDER-RIGHT: #666666 1px solid; BORDER-TOP: #666666 1px solid; DISPLAY: inline-block; PADDING-LEFT: 20px; FONT-SIZE: 10pt; BORDER-BOTTOM-WIDTH: 0px; PADDING-BOTTOM: 5px; BORDER-LEFT: #666666 1px solid; CURSOR: pointer; COLOR: #1b65b1; MARGIN-RIGHT: 5px; PADDING-TOP: 5px; TOP: 1px; HEIGHT: 20px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #fff
}
.et-activetab {
PADDING-RIGHT: 10px; PADDING-LEFT: 10px;COLOR: #ffffff; MARGIN-RIGHT: 5px;    BACKGROUND-REPEAT: repeat-x; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #009900
}
.et-inactivetab {
PADDING-RIGHT: 10px; PADDING-LEFT: 10px; COLOR: #009900; MARGIN-RIGHT: 5px
}
.et-separator {
BORDER-TOP-WIDTH: medium; BORDER-LEFT-WIDTH: medium; BORDER-BOTTOM: #666666 1px solid; HEIGHT: 2px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #666666; BORDER-RIGHT-WIDTH: medium
}
.et-tabrow {
 WHITE-SPACE: nowrap
 }
 .et-offscreen {
 MAX-WIDTH: 1px; MAX-HEIGHT: 1px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: -99999px
}</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
 (function(){
var AP = "", sec = 0, Header = "none", Split = "No", Expand = "", Print = "";
if (document.forms[0].elements["_wikiPageMode.value"] == "true" || document.forms[0].elements["MSOLayout_InDesignMode"].value == "1") {
    return;
}

var el = document.getElementsByTagName("SCRIPT"), p = el[el.length - 1], sT, a, sep, tabRow;

do {
    p = p.parentNode; sT = p.innerHTML.split("MSOZoneCell_WebPart");
} while (sT.length < 4 && p.parentNode.id != "MSO_ContentTable")

if (p.getAttribute("contenteditable") == "true") {
    return;
}

if (p.nodeName == "DIV") {
    sep = document.createElement("div"); p.insertBefore(sep, p.firstChild); tabRow = document.createElement("div"); p.insertBefore(tabRow, p.firstChild);
}
else {
    sep = document.createElement("td"); var sepTR = document.createElement("tr"); sepTR.appendChild(sep); tabRow = document.createElement("td"); var tabTR = document.createElement("tr"); tabTR.appendChild(tabRow); if (p.nodeName == "TBODY") { p.insertBefore(sepTR, p.firstChild); p.insertBefore(tabTR, p.firstChild); } else if (p.nodeName == "TR") { p.parentNode.insertBefore(tabTR, p); p.parentNode.insertBefore(sepTR, p); } else { return; }
}
sep.className = "et-separator"; tabRow.className = "et-tabrow";

var children = p.childNodes; p = p.parentNode; var etRoot = [], etHeader = [], etTab = [], tabsID = [];

for (var j = 0; j < children.length; j++) {
    try {
        var d = children[j].getElementsByTagName("td");
        for (i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
            if (d[i].id.indexOf("WebPartTitle") == 0) {
                var WPid = d[i].id.replace(/WebPartTitle/, "");
                if (d[i].innerHTML.indexOf("(Hidden)") == -1) {
                    var up = d[i]; while (up != children[j]) {
                        if (up.parentNode.innerHTML.indexOf('id=WebPart' + WPid + ' ') >= 0 || up.parentNode.innerHTML.indexOf('id="WebPart' + WPid + '" ') >= 0) {
                            WPid = "et" + WPid;
                            etHeader[WPid] = up;
                            etRoot[WPid] = children[j];
                            etTab[WPid] = d[i].getElementsByTagName("span")[0].cloneNode(true);
                            etTab[WPid].id = WPid;
                            etTab[WPid].className = "et-tab et-inactivetab";
                            etTab[WPid].onclick = function () { activateTab(this); };
                            tabRow.appendChild(etTab[WPid]);
                            tabsID.push(WPid);
                            break;
                        }
                        up = up.parentNode;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (e) { }
}
var Tabs = tabRow.getElementsByTagName("span"), TabCount = Tabs.length;
if (Split == "Yes") {
    var sd = document.createElement("div"), index = Math.floor(TabCount * 0.5);
    tabRow.insertBefore(sd, Tabs[index]);
}
if (AP.length && sec > 0) {
    sec = sec * 1000; interval = "";
    a = document.createElement("span"); a.innerHTML = "|>";
    a.className = "et-tab et-inactivetab";
    a.onclick = function () {
        if (interval == "") {
            this.innerHTML = "||"; interval = window.setInterval(function () { Autoplay(); }, sec)
        }
        else {
            this.innerHTML = "|>"; window.clearInterval(interval); interval = ""
        }
    };
    tabRow.appendChild(a);
    var Autoplay = function () {
        for (i = 0; i < TabCount; i++) if (Tabs[i].className == "et-tab et-activetab") {
            var j = (i + 1) % TabCount; activateTab(Tabs[j]); break
        }
    };
    if (AP == "Play") {
        a.innerHTML = "||";
        interval = window.setInterval(function () { Autoplay(); }, sec)
    };
}
if (Expand.length) {
    a = document.createElement("span"); a.innerHTML = Expand;
    a.className = "et-tab et-inactivetab";
    a.onclick = function () {
        for (i = 0; i < tabsID.length; i++) {
            etTab[tabsID[i]].className = "et-tab et-inactivetab";
            etRoot[tabsID[i]].className = etRoot[tabsID[i]].className.replace(/et-offscreen/g, "");
            etRoot[tabsID[i]].style.pageBreakAfter = "always";
            etHeader[tabsID[i]].style.display = "";
        }
    };
    tabRow.appendChild(a);
}
if (Print.length) {
    a = document.createElement("span");
    a.innerHTML = Print; a.className = "et-tab et-inactivetab";
    a.onclick = function () {
        this.style.display = "none";
        var f = document.getElementById("s4-workspace") || document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0], ed = p.parentNode.insertBefore(document.createElement(p.nodeName), p);
        f.appendChild(p);
        for (j = 0; j < f.childNodes.length - 1; j++) {
            try {
                f.childNodes[j].className += " et-offscreen";
            }
            catch (e) { }
        }
        a = document.createElement("span");
        a.innerHTML = "Back to Page";
        a.className = "et-tab et-inactivetab";
        a.onclick = function () {
            this.previousSibling.style.display = "inline-block";
            this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
            ed.parentNode.insertBefore(p, ed);
            ed.parentNode.removeChild(ed);
            for (j = 0; j < f.childNodes.length; j++) {
                try {
                    f.childNodes[j].className = f.childNodes[j].className.replace(/\s*et-offscreen/g, "");
                }
                catch (e) { }
            }
        };
        tabRow.appendChild(a);
    };
    tabRow.appendChild(a);
}
function activateTab(t) {
    document.cookie = tabsID.join("_") + "=" + t.id + ";path=/";
    for (i = 0; i < tabsID.length; i++) {
        etHeader[tabsID[i]].style.display = Header; if (t.id == tabsID[i]) {
            etTab[tabsID[i]].className = "et-tab et-activetab";
            etRoot[tabsID[i]].className = etRoot[tabsID[i]].className.replace(/\s*et-offscreen/g, "");
        }
        else { etTab[tabsID[i]].className = "et-tab et-inactivetab"; etRoot[tabsID[i]].className += " et-offscreen"; }
    }
} var m = GetCookie(tabsID.join("_")) ? GetCookie(tabsID.join("_")) : tabsID[0];
activateTab(etTab['etWPQ8']);
//activateTab(etTab[m]);
```

})();

Comment: Please let me know if somebody has solution?

Comment: I would suggest reformatting your code sample here so that it is more readable.

Comment: I have formatted it but I am not sure why it is not affecting

Comment: DOes anyone have an idea how to do it?splitting tabs into two rows?

Comment: DOes anyone have an idea how to do it?splitting tabs into two rows?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing .et-tab class to this

```
.et-tab { BORDER-RIGHT: #666666 1px solid; BORDER-TOP: #666666 1px solid; DISPLAY: block; PADDING-LEFT: 20px; FONT-SIZE: 10pt; BORDER-BOTTOM-WIDTH: 0px; PADDING-BOTTOM: 5px; BORDER-LEFT: #666666 1px solid; CURSOR: pointer; COLOR: #1b65b1; MARGIN-RIGHT: 5px; PADDING-TOP: 5px; TOP: 1px; HEIGHT: 20px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #fff }
```

I just changed the display to block instead of inline-block. Hope that does the trick!

Comment: I have tried it..but it is displaying all the tabs in different rows

Comment: Isnt that what you asked for? What do you want it to look like?

Comment: I want it to split in only in two rows..But when I use display:block..It is displaying each webpart in each row..I have 14 webparts..so it is displaying in 14 rows

Comment: I need to display 14 webparts into rowed tabscript